# When should I create thumbnail of an image?

Tags: php, image, performance, web-services, image-processing

I am working with a project. And there is feature user can upload image. That image will be used in different pages of website, with different sizes(eg: 200*300, 360*520, 700*1000).

I can create thumbnail two ways

1. while uploading image, create thumbnail with different size and store.
2. While displaying image src to some server side script, re-size image from there and print image, instead of displaying.

Which is the correct way to do? If I use 1st method, I think disk space will get full very fast, Is there any issue with 2nd method?

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of method 1 is that you won't risk resizing the same image twice simultaneously, and that you can provide quickly a version to display to your user.

But why would your disk get full fast if you size the images beforehand? That would happen if you re-size them to every possible size, so that's not a good idea.

Method 2 is more flexible. You just ask for an image in a given size and your script will produce it on the fly. This is a bit slower, of course, but you could cache the resized image so visitors will get the images fast, unless they are the first one to request an image in a specific size.

My suggestion: 
If you know which sizes you use on your website, you could use those sizes to resize the images in an early stage. You could even make a configuration on your website with a bunch of predefined image dimensions, which you can use on your website, and use those same configurations to scale the images when you upload them. This has some advantages:

Having a limited set of sizes will increase the chances of hitting the cache when visitors browse through your website. For instance, if you show a picture of X in the X detail page, and overview page includeing X, search results etcetera, and each of those pages uses a slightly different size, it is a waste of disk space and bandwidth.

And, if disk size is an issue, having a limited number of sizes also limits the disk space that the cached versions of these images consume.

Moreover, if you change or add a dimension, you could pregenerate all images for that size immediately, so visitors would benefit right away from the caches version.
And of course, it also makes it easier to purge the cache for images of a dimension that is no longer in the list, should you remove or change one.

If you choose this method, it makes it very easy to implement method 1 and pre-cache everything, but even if you would choose method 2 (if only as a fallback, should a cached version not exist), then still this would have benefits.